# Cannot determine type of file

Tags: python, mahotas

Hi i have just started learning image processing using python.
When i tried to open an image that i downloaded from the net, I keep getting this error and I have no idea about how to resolve it. Can anyone please help me with this?

```
>>> dna=mahotas.imread('dna.jpeg')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mahotas\io\freeimage.py", line 773, in imread
    img = read(filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mahotas\io\freeimage.py", line 444, in read
    bitmap = _read_bitmap(filename, flags)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mahotas\io\freeimage.py", line 490, in _read_bitmap
    'mahotas.freeimage: cannot determine type of file %s' % filename)
ValueError: mahotas.freeimage: cannot determine type of file dna.jpeg
```

Comment: Can you please format your code properly so that it is better readable? That increases your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: Are you sure dna.jpeg is a valid jpeg? Try creating a test .bmp from mspaint.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this looks like a pretty old thread but I found it recently because I had the same problem.

I think that the error message is misleading because it implies that the type of file is incorrect.

I fixed the problem by including the full path to the image file. For example, it could look something like:

```
dna = mahotas.imread('C:\Documents\dna.jpeg')
```