# Mahotas imread Cannot Determine Type of File

Tags: python, image, macos, canopy, mahotas

Hi I'm trying to use Mahotas to read an image. I'm getting an error saying "ValueError: mahotas.freeimage: cannot determine type of file picture.jpeg". I've tried several images and filetypes including bmp and png.

```
import mahotas
picture = mahotas.imread('picture.jpeg') #line throws error
```

This question was also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22437017/cannot-determine-type-of-file) by someone following the same [tutorial](http://pythonvision.org/basic-tutorial) as me, but without reaching a solution.

1. I'm running on Mac OSx 10.9.4
2. I'm using Canopy 1.4.1
3. I installed FreeImage 3.16.0 using Homebrew

Calling `$ brew doctor`returns the following warnings if those are of any help:

```
Warning: Enthought Python was found in your PATH.
This can cause build problems, as this software installs its own
copies of iconv and libxml2 into directories that are picked up by
other build systems.

Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
```

Comment: SOLVED: The error is misleading. I believe Mahotas couldn't find the location of the file, not the file type. By putting the the absolute address the issue was solved.

Comment: Glad it's working! FYI Stack Overflow norm would be to put your answer as an Answer (not a Comment) and mark it as the correct answer. That way it's very clear that the question has been solved.